# How do you activate the treasure in the garage?

Tags: steam, achievements, game-dev-tycoon

On Steam, this Achievement exists for this game:

> **Treasure Hunter**
>
> Activate the hidden treasure in the garage.

How do you unlock this? Where is the treasure and how do you activate it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is done by making a game named 'Pong' while in the garage. When you code the graphics part the animation on the wall will play.